# Can replacing LED light bulbs cause electric faults somewhere else in the house?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, led

Yesterday I replaced a few old halogen bulbs in the kitchen and the hallway with LED bulbs - B22 and MR16. I was reading that the MR16s could be tricky has they might need an LED driver, I ordered some LED bulbs which had the same voltage as the old bulbs and they worked fine. The B22 worked fine as well apart from some buzzing coming from the dimmer which is probably because of the fact that they were non-dimmable bulbs. Anyway, no apparent issues with both and I have used the lights fine all evening without problems.

This morning I went to the bathroom which is located one floor above and the light switch didn't work. Not sure if the problem is with the switch or somewhere else but electricity in the bathroom seems to be gone - none of the three lights in there nor the extraction fan turns on. It worked fine the day before, even after the bulbs had been changed.

Now I am wondering if I messed this up when replacing the lights the night before. I live in a rental property and have just moved in so I have no knowledge of the electric plan of the house. As I said earlier, the bathroom lights / electricity worked fine the day before after the bulbs had been changed, since I used it before going to bed. This morning the lights in the hallway and kitched still worked fine too.

Or is it just a coincidence and the switch / circuit reached the end of its days?

Comment: Are the new LEDs and the light switch upstairs on the same circuit?

Comment: @mmathis sorry, no idea - might make sense since the bathroom is located directly above the kitchen

Comment: Check any and all GFCI’s in your house and make certain they are not tripped, start with any located in that bathroom.

Comment: Including GFCI breakers in the circuit breaker panel, GFCi receptacles or deadfaces *near* the panel for no apparent reason, or in unusual locations.   My money is, it's vanishingly unlikely LED replacement bulbs could kill a wiring circuit, especially downline from a dimmer, which should "take the hit" if there was any hit to take, which I really doubt there is.   Coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a coincidence, the wall switch was mechanically jammed - a bit for force nudged it back into place. Thanks all.